# Calculating days record open with Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to use a excel formula to estimate how long a record has been open based off of two fields and today's date. I however want to have the formula to be blank if the "Closed Date" is not populated. I haven't had success with getting this result.

*Example in Excel:*

```
|   | A - Open Date   | B - Closed Date |
|---|-----------------|-----------------|
| 1 | 02 January 2019 | 04 January 2019 |
| 2 | 02 January 2019 |                 |
| 3 |                 |                 |
```

I currently am using the following formula for each pertaining row;

`=IF(B1>0, B1-A1,TODAY()-A1)`

`=IF(B2>0, B2-A2,TODAY()-A2)`

`=IF(B3>0, B3-A3,TODAY()-A3)`

For the first row I will get *2* which is correct.  The second row will also have *2* but will go up each day which is also correct. The third row will have a large number like *43559* which is due to there being no open date in `A3`. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this as an answer as I think you mean:

- If "Open Date" is not populated show a blank
- If "Closed Date" is not populated use todays date.

`=IF(A1="","",IF(B1="",TODAY(),B1)-A1)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I was to put in simple terms I'd say this: If Open Date is blank, show a blank. If Open Date is not blank but Closed date is, calculate how many days between Open date and today's date. If Open and Closed dates are not blank then calculate the number of days between those dates.

Comment: I also tried this formula but got 1/2/1900        =IF(A1=" "," ",IF(B1<>" ",B1-A1,TODAY()-A1))

Comment: Does your formula have a space betwwen the speech marks - `" "`?  Remove the space - `""`.

Comment: FINALLY WORKED! Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe*: `=IF(B1="","",B1-A1)` ??

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution but this doesn't work.

Comment: You say row 2 is correct with a value of _2_, but you want the result to be blank if the "Closed Date" is not populated - which it isn't in row 2, so should be blank and not 2.  Do you mean if "Open Date" is not populated?